# Building a Maven Project with Files in a Local Repo

Tags: maven-3

I've installed two libraries to my local repository (JGraph and JGraphtT). I used this command:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.jgrapht -DartifactId=jgrapht -Dversion=0.8.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=./jgrapht.jar
```

and similar for JGraph. I can see that the two Jar files are in my local repository.

When I try to create Eclipse classpath and build files from the directory of my project's POM file (using mvn eclipse:eclipse), I get this error:

> [WARNING] Missing POM for org.jrapht:jgrapht:jar:0.8.3

and similar for JGraph.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? My settings.xml file has the local repository enabled.

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: Do you have m2e installed in Eclipse? Does the build on command line working via mvn clean package ?

Comment: Hi, I have m2e installed but these errors aren't happening in Eclipse. The errors show when I run "mvn eclipse:eclipse" from the command line. Also, I just tried "mvn clean package" and it gives the error message: "Failed to execute goal....the following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jgrapht:jgrapht:jar:0.8.3, org.jgraph:jgraph:jar:5.8.3-2".

Comment: Could you show us your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to include the POM.

Comment: Please ignore this question. I've spotted the problem.

Comment: Can you explain the solution cause it might be interessting for others.

Comment: I made a spelling mistake in the POM. Looking at it with fresh eyes made me spot it. Thanks to people who have commented.